# How to Implement left and right cursor for editing a text on uart serial?

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, putty, uart

I am implementing a minimal command line in serial terminal using TivaC board from texas instruments. using Putty

cursor detection is already enabled by application so I don't have to delete the escape sequences generated by the cursors on the terminal like "esc[A", "esc[B".. etc

However in my code where I am storing the char input in a string[] array of size 80, I am not able to implement left and right cursor edits. if I press left I should be able to move my cursor to the required position and should be able to edit the texts.

**Behavior:**
when I press the left from the keyboard the cursor should travel left and allow the user to enter the character where ever the user wants to. However in my case it is able to travel left (already enabled in PUTYY) but not able to add the required character.

**For example**

$>echo hello

$>echo hellmo  (char entered at 5th position)

**ideal output:-**

hellmo

**my output:-**

hellom

**See the code commented as** `//left`

`getcUart0();` gets characters from the from user.
`putsUart(char *string);` puts a string into the serial

```
void command_line(void)
{
    char char_input = 0;
    int char_count =0;

    // Get Input from User
    putsUart0("\r\n");
    putsUart0("\033[1;32m$>\033[0m");          //Print Input to let user know to start typing, foreground color:Yellow

    while(1)
    {
        //take input from user
        char_input = getcUart0();           

        //Exit on carriage return
        if (char_input == 13 || carriage_return)
        {
            string[char_count] = '\0';
            carriage_return = 0;
            char_count = 0;
            break;
        }

        // Cursor processing
        if (char_input == 27)
        {
            char next_1 = getcUart0();
            char next_2 = getcUart0();

             //nullify the behavior of up key
            if(next_1 == 91 && next_2 == 65)      //up
            {
                putsUart0("\033[B");
                char_input = '\0';
                continue;
            }
            //nullify the behavior of down key
            else if(next_1 == 91 && next_2 == 66) //down
            {
                putsUart0("\033[A");
                char_input = '\0';
                continue;
            }
            //left key 
            else if(next_1 == 91 && next_2 == 68) //left
            {
                int temp_count = char_count;
                char temp_inp = char_input;
                char_count--;
                string[temp_count] = temp_inp;
                putcUart0(string[temp_count]);
                continue;

            }
        }

        //Process backspace key
        if (char_input == 8 || char_input == 127)
        {
            //putsUart0("\r\nBackspace detect");

            if(char_count <= 0)
            {
                putsUart0("\033[C");

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                putcUart0(' ');
                putsUart0("\033[D");
                char_count--;
                continue;
            }
        }

        //convert uppercase to lower before storing in string
        if (char_input >= 65 && char_input <= 90)
            string[char_count++] = char_input + 32;

        else
            string[char_count++] = char_input;

        //check for buffer overflow
        if (char_count == MAX_SIZE)
        {
            putsUart0("\r\nCan't exceed more than 80 chars");   

            reset_buffer();                                      
            *string = 0;

            break;
        }

    }

    putsUart0("\r\n");

}
```

Comment: You would do well to describe what your code does compared to what you want it to do.  You have only said what you want it to do, leaving us to figure out what it might actually do.  As it stands any answer I would give would discard all your code and start again, because that would be easier that figuring out how to fix the code without information on how it currently behaves.

Comment: You are nul-terminating your input at `char_count`, but if enter is pressed after you have cursor-left to the middle of the input, you will have truncated the input.

Comment: If I press enter then the string has to be null terminated right? this happens only  when I am finished typing. other wise as you can see its a while loop...
How do I simulate the way we write usually on any console.?

Comment: Also check the updated details

Comment: yes it must be nul terminated, but at the end of the text, not the cursor position, which need not be at the end.  You need two variables - I suggest `cursor_pos` and `cursor_max`.  `cursor_max` is updated whenever `cursor_pos > cursor_max`. The nul terminator goes at `cursor_max + 1`.  I started re-writing your code, but it turned into a bit of a project; you need a more specific question.  It is more complex if you have to deal with backspace and insertion - you have to move the data and re-present the on screen text.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, let me try this.